# Choppy Voice and Round Trip Time

Tags: voip

Since last Wednesday, I am dealing with choppy voice in my VoIP service. I have made no changes relative with our telephones (no switch/phone management or changing any equipment) and I disabled every new firewall/nat rule I have configured (note that any of these rules have been up and running for at least two weeks before the problem). I don't see any packet loss but I have seen an increase to rta to performance graphs in Nagios XI the same time the problem started (from 1-2 ms to 10-100 ms). I have rebooted my devices and checked the configuration with the providers of our services (VoIP telephony, ADSL merger) and we have not reached to any conclusions.

I am new in the business and I would appreciate some ideas about what could cause this increase and if it is relevant to the voice problem, so I can check it. Please bother me with your questions.

Answer (score 1):

The number one cause of poor VoIP audio quality is variable latency (VoIP codecs can usually deal with high latency OK - it's when latency is quite variable when you end up with quality issues). It's likely that your traffic is passing through a congested link (or links), which you may or may not have any control of. You'll need to gather statistics from your local router and internet circuit to see if that is where the congestion is happening.

If it is, then consider implementing traffic shaping rules to prioritize your VoIP traffic.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I assume that this is the case but I am curious what provoked it. Can it be a faulty cable or patch panel? Because I did not make any changes and I have read (maybe this is totally trash) that with rebooting the devices you can solve the problem temporarily. When I rebooted my switches and routers, nothing changed to see if it is congested links. I have tried to connect two phone devices directly to the router (no switches) and there is still high rta value. In your opinion, is there a connection between that value and the problem? Thank you for your patience.

Comment: The congestion is very unlikely to be on the internal side of your router, and rebooting devices won't fix congested links. There is no short-cut here. You'll need to collect statistics, analyze them to identify possible bottlenecks, then decide what to do to mitigate them.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved.

I have gathered statistics as EEAA said and we found that the problem was on the ethernet interface of our ADSL modem, so we replaced it. The company told us, it was a hardware problem.